# Silverlight MJPEG viewer

Tags: silverlight, streaming, media-player, mediaelement, mjpeg

I would like to consume a Motion Jpeg stream from an IP camera and ideally view it using the media element.  I was hoping to find some ready made samples.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really nice example (and controls to download) from channel9. Check visit [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder)

Unfortunately the provided dll is out of browser only which I suspect will be a bit of a downer.

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of native dlls, transcoding the meterial on the fly on your server is probably your best - if not only - option.